# Automatic attribute for chef environment

Tags: chef-infra

I'm writing a chef recipe and I want to use the node's *environment* attribute. I'm not able to find something similar to automatic attributes for `fqdn`, `hostname`, or `ipaddress` in order to automatic discover the node environment like in the example below.

```rb
:zabbix => {
  :ipaddress   => node['ipaddress'],   # returns the IP as exected
  :environment => node['environment']  # returns nothing
}
```

How can I access the node's environment?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your problem is.... node['fqdn'] and node['ipaddress'] are examples of node attributes that are set automatically by ohai. Documented here: https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#automatic-attributes. .... Are you saying their values are empty?

Comment: No I said that I can't use the ENVIRONMENT attribute or I'm using it wrong or probably there is no automatic environment attribute like for ipaddress or fqdn. In the example with zabbix I'm able to use in my template the attribute with IPadress but not the one which should get my node environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a node's environment through

```rb
node.chef_environment
```

Comment: I fixed it but for the future the env is not an attribute.

Comment: yeah we should also make it a real attribute -- i found that highly confusing recently